# Is it possible to bind a value to a 2D array cell, map or list in JSF?

Tags: jsf, el

Something like:

```
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.array[0][2]}" /> <!-- 2D array -->
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.map[key][2]}" /> <!-- an array as value of a map entry -->
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.map[key][2]}" /> <!-- now a collection inside map -->
```

is that possible?

Comment: Try it out and give us feedback :)

Comment: Of course I tried it out like that but it won't accept the syntax.